# Some apps crash immediately, not opening at all, after Soft Navigation Bar is enabled via registry edit/hack

Tags: windows-10-mobile, lumia, apps, navigation-key

I'm using Microsoft Lumia 532 with w10mobile. The navigation bar hardware keys (back, home, search) of my phone are damaged. So I need the Soft Navigation Bar on my phone. But my device doesn't have it, so I Google for it. And I found that to enable Soft Navigation Bar on an unsupported Lumia device.

For that I have to Interop Unlock my device and make some registry edit, for that I have to deploy a root tool which helped me to Interop Unlock and also deploy customPFD registry editor and it also provides the option for enable soft navigation bar. And by enabling it I successfully got the navigation bar but as a side effect suddenly some apps started crashing, not even open at all, some are showing splash screen and some are not, but close immediately.

Only built for Windows 10 apps ran smoothly, and Windows Phone 8.1 like WhatsApp, UC browser and many other apps close immediately after opening.

These steps I followed for solving the issues but nothing happened:

1. Reinstalled all the apps
2. Restore the registry value to default
3. Uninstall both root tool and customPFD
4. Manually edit the registry
5. Install INTEROP TOOL which edit the registry without the need of interop 
   unlock, got the nav bar but still same problem

Hard reset solved the problem but I lost my nav bar!
How to stop those app crashing problem without hard reset and without losing my soft navigation bar?

Comment: So which problem are you trying to solve here? The hardware fault, the apps crashing because of the soft keys, or something else?

Comment: That app crashing problem only!! I don't know how to stop those immediate crashes of wp8.1 apps. I need to run all my important wp8.1 apps. Plzzz help

Comment: So what registry hack did you try?

Comment: 1. First I opened customPFD and in REGISTRY TREE section followed the path "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE /SOFTWARE /Microsoft /Shell /NavigationBar", and create a KEY called "SoftwareModeEnabled" of type "dword-integer-32bits" and assign a VALUE "1" to it.... That's it...after a restart Navigation bar appears, as well as apps are crashes. This is the first approach done by me, but when some wp8.1aaps won't work, i did a reset

Comment: 2. Secondly, as I am new to customPFD, i don't know about there is TWEAK section also present,   i follwed "TWEAK > General Tweak > Enable navigation bar"... It will directly enable nav bar (under the hood it done the same registry edit which I above mentioned). And after a restart nav bar appears but same crash problem

Answer (score 2):

I recently enabled soft mode navigation bar, but UC browser and WhatsApp and many more apps crashed immediately after opening. Then I disabled the virtual bar by using the value changing 1 to 0 in

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE  /SOFTWARE /Microsoft /Shell  /NavigationBar
```

and created a key called `SoftwareModeEnabled` of type `dword-integer-32bits` and  assigned a VALUE "0". By doing this the nav bar was gone, but  apps are crashed like before.

Then I found three keys "isdoubletapoffenabled", "isusermanaged" and "ishintenabled". Don't do anything with "ishintenabled" by changing the value 0 to 1 -  it will turn off your WiFi and mobile service (SIM card). It has its own value 0 by default. But the other two keys are usable. Change the two keys (double tap and user managed) from 1 to 0. Restart your phone and then you will able to open all apps like before without any problem and no crashes.